# wxGrid GetSelectedCells returns empty array

Tags: c++, windows, wxwidgets

I want to delete selected rows when the use click on a button.

so far the code looks like that:

```
this->grid_ = new wxGrid(parent, ...)
this->grid_->SetSelectionMode(wxGrid::wxGridSelectCells);
// Later, whene the button is clicked
this->grid_->SetFocus();
wxGridCellCoordsArray wx_cells = this->grid_->GetSelectedCells();
```

The problem is that the `wx_cells` variable is always empty whatever I select.
I tried with GetSelectedRows with no success.
I've added `SetFocus` and `SetSelectionMode` hoping it would help but it did not.

How can I get this to work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of wxgrid are you using? There seems to be an issue with old wxgrid that it always return empty when calling GetSelectedCells. Perhaps you can refer to http://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?t=6335 to try if it fits in your case.

Comment: My summary of that forum post so far: `wxGridSelectCells` mode does not work. `GetSelectedRows`, `GetSelectedCols`, `GetSelectedCells` don't work. The solution is to use blocks: `GetSelectionBlockTopLeft` and `GetSelectionBlockBottomRight`. If you want to do something simple/cusom you can also go through the grid cells and call `IsInSelection`